# Format of CLI instructions in IBM 360

Tags: assembly, mainframe

I have a instruction `CLI =F'3',3`
I want to know whether it will compare the value 3 with the contents of register 3 or will it compare value 3 with other value '3'.
please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the instruction in the Principles of Operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you'd ever want to know about IBM360 is here:
http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/360

The assembly language is explained in: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/360/asm/C28-6514-5_IBM_System_360_Assembler_Language_Level_E_F_Dec67.pdf

`CLI` stands for logical compare immediate.
So you should know you're comparing against an immediate, not the contents of a register.

Here's the relevant section of that manual:

[image]

Note that you're using the implicit operand version, so the relevant column is 5, not 4.
S1 is the storage register.
I2 is the immediate value `S1` is compared with.

So the answer is option A:

> it will compare the value 3 with the contents of register 3

See [page 119 and 120 for details](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/360/asm/C28-6514-5_IBM_System_360_Assembler_Language_Level_E_F_Dec67.pdf).

Comment: Are you sure? Shouldn't a CLI to compare R3 with F'3' should be: CLI R3,F'3' - the 'I' instructions (CLI, MVI) don't use literals for their operands. But then a fullword (F'3') is too long so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Sad to say that this answer is incorrect as Steve Ives suggests. The CLI instruction as given will compare the first byte of the literal (which would be a zero) to X'03" as explained in the answer below.

Comment: PS: The first part of Steve Ives comment is also incorrect. If you want to compare a single byte in a register against an immediate value, instructions like CLM are your friend, not CLI.

Answer (score 0):

`CLI =F'3',3` will compare the first byte of literal F'3' with a value of X'03'.

These will ***not*** compare equal because the *first byte* of literal F'3' will be X'00'. F'3' generates a fullword (four-byte) value of 3 with leading binary zeros, i.e. X'00000003' aligned on a full-word boundary.